# Show next object OnClickListener Android Studios

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm developing a basic drinking game app using Android Studios and Java where I have a deck of 52 cards and each card has a different challenge connected to it.

What I'm currently trying to do is that whenever I click on the card that is showing on the screen, it should move to the next card in the deck.

**How do I go about making it so that clicking a card gives me the next card in line?**

P.S sorry for the object-creation and addition to deck, I know there are simpler ways to do this but it is what it is...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

    //Spades
    Card AS = new Card(1,0, R.drawable.as);
    Card TwoS = new Card(2,0, R.drawable.tws);
    Card ThreeS = new Card(3,0,R.drawable.trs);
    Card FourS = new Card(4,0,R.drawable.fys);
    Card FiveS = new Card(5,0,R.drawable.fes);
    Card SixS = new Card(6,0,R.drawable.ses);
    Card SevenS = new Card(7,0,R.drawable.sjs);
    Card EightS = new Card(8,0,R.drawable.ats);
    Card NineS = new Card(9,0,R.drawable.nis);
    Card TenS = new Card(10,0,R.drawable.tis);
    Card JS = new Card(11,0,R.drawable.js);
    Card QS = new Card(12,0,R.drawable.qs);
    Card KS = new Card(13,0,R.drawable.ks);

    //Hearts
    Card AH = new Card(1,1,R.drawable.ah);
    Card TwoH = new Card(2,1,R.drawable.twh);
    Card ThreeH = new Card(3,1,R.drawable.trh);
    Card FourH = new Card(4,1,R.drawable.fyh);
    Card FiveH = new Card(5,1,R.drawable.feh);
    Card SixH = new Card(6,1,R.drawable.seh);
    Card SevenH = new Card(7,1,R.drawable.sjh);
    Card EightH = new Card(8,1,R.drawable.ath);
    Card NineH = new Card(9,1,R.drawable.nih);
    Card TenH = new Card(10,1,R.drawable.tih);
    Card JH = new Card(11,1,R.drawable.jh);
    Card QH = new Card(12,1,R.drawable.qh);
    Card KH = new Card(13,1,R.drawable.kh);

    //Diamonds
    Card AD = new Card(1,2,R.drawable.ad);
    Card TwoD = new Card(2,2,R.drawable.twd);
    Card ThreeD = new Card(3,2,R.drawable.trd);
    Card FourD = new Card(4,2,R.drawable.fyd);
    Card FiveD = new Card(5,2,R.drawable.fed);
    Card SixD = new Card(6,2,R.drawable.sed);
    Card SevenD = new Card(7,2,R.drawable.sjd);
    Card EightD = new Card(8,2,R.drawable.atd);
    Card NineD = new Card(9,2,R.drawable.nid);
    Card TenD = new Card(10,2,R.drawable.tid);
    Card JD = new Card(11,2,R.drawable.jd);
    Card QD = new Card(12,2,R.drawable.qd);
    Card KD = new Card(13,2,R.drawable.kd);

    //Clubs
    Card AC = new Card(1,3,R.drawable.ac);
    Card TwoC = new Card(2,3,R.drawable.twc);
    Card ThreeC = new Card(3,3,R.drawable.trc);
    Card FourC = new Card(4,3,R.drawable.fyc);
    Card FiveC = new Card(5,3,R.drawable.fec);
    Card SixC = new Card(6,3,R.drawable.sec);
    Card SevenC = new Card(7,3,R.drawable.sjc);
    Card EightC = new Card(8,3,R.drawable.atc);
    Card NineC = new Card(9,3,R.drawable.nic);
    Card TenC = new Card(10,3,R.drawable.tic);
    Card JC = new Card(11,3,R.drawable.jc);
    Card QC = new Card(12,3,R.drawable.qc);
    Card KC = new Card(13,3,R.drawable.kc);


    ImageView ShownCard;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Adds all Spades to the deck
        deck.add(AS);
        deck.add(TwoS);
        deck.add(ThreeS);
        deck.add(FourS);
        deck.add(FiveS);
        deck.add(SixS);
        deck.add(SevenS);
        deck.add(EightS);
        deck.add(NineS);
        deck.add(TenS);
        deck.add(JS);
        deck.add(QS);
        deck.add(KS);
        //Adds all Hearts to the deck
        deck.add(AH);
        deck.add(TwoH);
        deck.add(ThreeH);
        deck.add(FourH);
        deck.add(FiveH);
        deck.add(SixH);
        deck.add(SevenH);
        deck.add(EightH);
        deck.add(NineH);
        deck.add(TenH);
        deck.add(JH);
        deck.add(QH);
        deck.add(KH);
        //Adds all Diamonds to the deck
        deck.add(AD);
        deck.add(TwoD);
        deck.add(ThreeD);
        deck.add(FourD);
        deck.add(FiveD);
        deck.add(SixD);
        deck.add(SevenD);
        deck.add(EightD);
        deck.add(NineD);
        deck.add(TenD);
        deck.add(JD);
        deck.add(QD);
        deck.add(KD);
        //Adds all Clubs to the deck
        deck.add(AC);
        deck.add(TwoC);
        deck.add(ThreeC);
        deck.add(FourC);
        deck.add(FiveC);
        deck.add(SixC);
        deck.add(SevenC);
        deck.add(EightC);
        deck.add(NineC);
        deck.add(TenC);
        deck.add(JC);
        deck.add(QC);
        deck.add(KC);

        //Shuffles deck of cards so next one printed is random
        Collections.shuffle(deck);

        ShownCard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ShownCard);

        ShownCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
    }


}
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an `Iterator` on your `ArrayList`. An `Iterator` provides you with the next element in the iteration. Your `clickListener` would look like this:

```
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
        // Notice change below:
        Iterator<Card> deckIterator = deck.iterator();

        ShownCard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ShownCard);

        ShownCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Card nextCard = deckIterator.next()

            }
        });
```

Additionally, you can use the iterator to determine if there is another element by calling: `deckIterator.hasNext()`.